# Research Ahead of Time

Tags: hearts-of-iron-4

I notice that you can build up some research time before picking a tech.

However, each day tick also reduces how much time penalty (50% extra cost if the tech is still 6 months away as an example).

So I was wondering is it best to stack research bonus from the electronic tree and wait until that year to start work on tech? Or just start work on it and ignore the penalty?

There are some tech that can be a "huge game-changer" like infantry equipment 2 that makes it worthwhile to ignore penalty a bit. However, there are some tech that you may want to rush but comes with a huge penalty like nuclear tech in the 1940s.

Basically what is the best way to min-max research speed?

Comment: I guess we all have tried to do the math and stopped at some point, because min-max just research days  cannot take into count uncomparables. For example, maybe a few days of research gain is less important than starting production of newer version equipment N months earlier.

Answer (score 1):

> Basically what is the best way to min-max research speed?

- **Never** research with the ahead of time penalty.
- Change **trade law** to `Free Trade`(−10% research time).
- Prioritize research of the **Engineering technology** tree:

  1. 1936 - Electronic Mechanical Engineering (-2% research time)
  2. 1936 - Mechanical Computing (-3% research time)
  3. 1938 - Computing Machine (-3% research time)
  4. 1940 - Improved Computing Machine (-5% research time)
  5. 1940 - Atomic Research (-2% research time)
  6. 1942 - Advanced Computing Machine (-5% research time)
- Pick **designers, concerns and theorists** giving bonus for what you are researching now (or about to begin).
- Pick **National Focus** giving research bonus or increasing research slots.
- **License military technology** for units that you wish to research (with [Death or Dishonor](https://hoi4.paradoxwikis.com/Death_or_Dishonor) on).
- **Boost** the research of doctrines and some Naval techs using Army XP / Air XP / Navy XP.
- If your country is part of a **technology sharing group** (with [Together for Victory](https://hoi4.paradoxwikis.com/Together_for_Victory) on) pick technologies researched by other nations.
- Pick the **Technology Sharing** focus (with [Together for Victory](https://hoi4.paradoxwikis.com/Together_for_Victory) on) if no other focus can help with research.

> Or just start work on it and ignore the penalty?

You ignore the penalty for things that take a long time to develop or you need them when the war starts:

- Atomic bomb.
- Naval technology research tree (capital ships take a long time to build with [Man the Guns](https://hoi4.paradoxwikis.com/Man_the_Guns) on).

Comment: Also as a democratic country, you can give refugees to German and Italian scientists for an extra 5% each.

Answer (score 0):

One min maxing technique would be:
The saved up time can be used at any time, so it is recommended to use it at the end of research as the penalty goes dow with time.

1. Start a research on line 1.
2. Now it is 30+ days away from it's traget and you have a research line 2 which just got free.
3. Keep line 2 free from 30 days - maximum stored bonus.
4. Select research line 1 and pick any other tech you want to research.
5. Select research line 2 (with stored bonus) and pick the original technology - the bonus will be substracted from research time.

Also if you have dynamic research bonuses like from allies or focus modifiers, you can do the same trick, but put the research back to the line 1 and save time. Some bonus are applied only when you start the start the research on the line and static to the time.

**In general best way to min-max research is to use focuses, allies, blueprints, spies and pick what you need at the right time (no need to research something you cannot produce yet as you dont have IC).**